# can't add a custom marker to Google maps ( JS )

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Was wondering, how do I add a custom marker to google maps, JavaScript, integrated into my site.

This code adds a regular marker:

```
var marker = new GMarker(center);
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

but where do I insert an image tag (say, "marker.png" ) for it to appear instead of the regular google marker?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in [the Google Maps documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/) page [about custom icons](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Custom_Icons).  In particular, see this line in `createMarker`:

```
letteredIcon.image = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + letter + ".png";
```

You should be able to replace that with your own image.  More info on `GIcon`s is [in the API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GIcon).

Comment: Thanks man! now it works.
var towerIcon = new GIcon();
towerIcon.image = "tower.png";
towerIcon.iconSize = new GSize(100, 100);
towerIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(5, 50);
markerOptions = { icon:towerIcon };

map.addOverlay(new GMarker(center, markerOptions));